# Access denied for user root

Tags: python, mysql

I use a Python [script](https://bitbucket.org/jason_c_kwan/orthomcl_docker/src/master/run_orthomcl.py) not as sudo. However, I got

```
mysql -u root -pPAssw0rd -e "create database orthomcl"
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Here is how the script tries to create a database.

```
if 3 in stages_to_do:
    # Set up database
    command = 'mysql -u root -pPAssw0rd -e "create database orthomcl"'
    print(command)
    os.system(command)
    command = 'orthomclInstallSchema ' + config_file + ' orthomclInstallSchema_sql.log'
    print(command)
    os.system(command)
```

How is it possible to solve the access denied error?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enter a database in localhost with the root user, you need to execute the command with superuser privileges (sudo). You can either run the python file with sudo or change the command to `'sudo mysql -u root -pPAssw0rd -e "create database orthomcl"'` You must enter your sudo password at some point either way.

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to create a user which is not root and run the script without sudo?

Comment: @user977828 yes, in order to do that you need to log in the databse as root through the terminal and then enter ```CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';```. You'll need to grant some privileges to this user if you want it to be able to manage a database though. Here's a guide I've just found on the internet: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql . I hope this helps you.

Comment: This is misleading. The System root is completely different from MySQL root. There are VERY FEW valid reasons for running the MySQL client with sudo.

Comment: @RoryBrowne they are different things indeed, but you do need sudo to enter as root to the database by default (at least for mariadb or mysql). I'm completely sure about this as I have a mariadb database running in my computer and it won't let me in as root unless I execute the command with sudo, even if I type the correct password for the database.

Comment: Seems my previous comment is out of date, and @Asriel is correct. A default install of MariaDB now uses an auth_socket authentication mechanism, which checks which user connected locally by checking which user is connected to a unix socket.